# Nullpointer on creating simple tutorial and starting up

Tags: javafx, codenameone

I am trying to get started on code one, but the hello world fails out of the box...

All, I did was create Hello World (Bare Bones) in jdk 11 and I get a Nullpointer on this line..

```
    final Label apple = new Label(theme.getImage("apple-icon.png"));
```

The 'theme' is initialized in the init() method.  Is the newer version of codeones not calling init making the hello world example useless?

When I try to debug in jdk 11, it fails with this in Intellij(note it displays the exact jdk11 version if you need it).  Because of that and not knowing how to log yet, I could not debug the issue further.

```
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.5.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:53436,suspend=y,server=n -Xms128m -Xmx2048m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=\"\" -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true -Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off -Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:ErrorFile=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_idea_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_idea.hprof -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -javaagent:/Users/dean/Library/Caches/IdeaIC2019.3/captureAgent/debugger-agent.jar -classpath "/Users/dean/workspace/keepInTouch/out/production/keepInTouch:/Users/dean/workspace/keepInTouch/src:/Users/dean/workspace/keepInTouch/lib/CodenameOne.jar:/Users/dean/workspace/keepInTouch/JavaSE.jar:native/internal_tmp:lib/impl/cls:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.codename1.impl.javase.Simulator com.kit.phone.MyKit
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
            Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53436', transport: 'socket'
    JavaFX Not loaded.  Classpath=/Users/dean/workspace/keepInTouch/out/production/keepInTouch:/Users/dean/workspace/keepInTouch/src:/Users/dean/workspace/keepInTouch/lib/CodenameOne.jar:/Users/dean/workspace/keepInTouch/JavaSE.jar:native/internal_tmp:lib/impl/cls:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar . Adding to classpath
    Adding JavaFX to your project properties file at nbproject/project.properties
    JavaFX should be correctly loaded the next time you run this project.
            Restarting JVM with JavaFX in the classpath.
    NOTE: If you are trying to debug the project, you'll need to cancel this run and try running debug on the project again.  JavaFX should now be in your classpath.
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
            ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection refused
    ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
    JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [:732]
    Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53436', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: Could you add the error stack trace?

Comment: Post a [MCVE] and the complete stack trace

Answer (score 1):

Oracle removed Java FX from JDK 9 and newer. Hence if you use JDK 11 which doesn't have it you get that error in the debugger.

Try running outside of the debugger (regular run). It will download JavaFX implicitly and fix itself. Then kill the VM and run again. Notice that you MUST have an internet connection for this run so we can download the JavaFX libraries matching your VM.

Also make sure your plugin is up to date.

NOTE: We use Java FX for the browser and media functionality which is unavailable elsewhere. This is only used in the simulator and not in the device. The failure in that case is a failure of the simulator and not one of Codename One.